# Multiple values in one attribute (such as class) in simplexml (using PHP)

Tags: php, attributes, simplexml, libxml2

If I try to add the same attribute twice to an element via simplexml, I get the following error:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute() [function.SimpleXMLElement-addAttribute]: Attribute already exists...
```

As a workaround, I'm using if-else statements for the three possibilities:

```
if ($a && $b) {
    $node -> addAttribute("class", "a b");
 }
 else if($a) {
    $node -> addAttribute("class", "a");
 }
 else if ($b) {
    $node -> addAttribute("class", "b");
 }
```

But that feels a bit clunky,and not very scalable. Is there a better way anyone is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using [`SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addAttribute.php), maybe you can just use array-access to the parameters ?

For instance, considering you have that portion of code :

```
$str = <<<XML
<root>
    <elem>glop</elem>
</root>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
var_dump($xml->elem);
```

Which gives this output :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
  string 'glop' (length=4)
```

You can add the "class=a" attribute this way :

```
$xml->elem['class'] .= 'a ';
var_dump($xml->elem);
```

Which will give you this output :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array
      'class' => string 'a ' (length=2)
  string 'glop' (length=4)
```

And, then, add the "class=b" attribute by concatenating that value to the existing value of class, this way :

```
$xml->elem['class'] .= 'b ';
var_dump($xml->elem);
```

And you obtain :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array
      'class' => string 'a b ' (length=4)
  string 'glop' (length=4)
```

Note the space at the end of the attribute's value ; maybe you'll want to clean this, using trim :

```
$xml->elem['class'] = trim($xml->elem['class']);
var_dump($xml->elem);
```

Et voila :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[8]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array
      'class' => string 'a b' (length=3)
  string 'glop' (length=4)
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: You're my hero of the day. Awesome help.